# C++ - Setting a node to NULL doesn't work

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
  int val;
  node* left, *right;
};

void _delete(node *root)
{
  root = NULL;
}
void change(node *root)
{
  root->val = 6;
}
int main()
{
  node * root = new node;
  root->val = 5;
  change(root);
  _delete(root);
  cout<<root->val<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is 6. It seems as if the `_delete` function has no effect on the root node but `change` function has an effect on the root node. It is almost as if `delete` treats the argument passed as a local variable but `change` treats the argument as a global variable. Is there anything that I am missing out or is this normal? If it is normal, please explain.

Comment: "It seems as if the _delete function has no effect on the root node" It indeed does not. Why do you think it should? "change treats the argument as a global variable" no, it doesn't. It changes `root->val`. `root` is still local to it.

Comment: Your code also leaks memory, since it is not deallocating the object it allocated using operator `new`. Setting a pointer to some other value does not deallocate the object the pointer points to. And if `_delete` is supposed to set the pointer to `NULL` then you later dereference a `NULL` pointer in `cout<<root->val<<endl;`. PS: Names starting with underscores are reserved in C++.

Comment: You should use operator `delete` to delete the node's memory, then set the pointer to null.  Otherwise, the program has the memory allocated but it's location will be lost and you won't be able to recover it, a.k.a. *memory leak*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you pass the pointer *by value* in your `_delete` function, the value in the caller is not changed.

The quickest fix is to write

`void _delete(node*& root)`

i.e. pass the pointer by *reference*: note the `&`; you might also want to call `delete` on the pointer there too else you leak memory. The function `change` works as it is since you are using the *pointer to member* operator `->`.